# where to locate my vcvarsall.bat?

Tags: find, cygwin

I have downloaded vcredist_x64.exe  and installed it .

[image]

I can't locate the vcvarsall.bat in my pc with `$ find /cygdrive/  -name   "vcvarsall.bat"` in cygwin environment.

Where is my vcvarsall.bat ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure vcredist will install vcvarsall.bat ? I believe this just installs visual C++ runtime libraries, not the development tools.

In any case, you should try: `find /cygdrive/c -iname 'vcvarsall.bat'` to do a case insentsitive search.

Usually you can find this script by looking at the `VS[version]COMNTOOLS` environment variable:

```
cd %VS110COMNTOOLS%
cd ..
cd ..
cd VC
```

In cygwin shell:

```
cd "$(cygpath "$VS110COMNTOOLS")/../../VC"
```

Visual Studio is available there: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40787

Comment: how to install the  development tools?